# What is the best way to keep an abandoned facility running with no external power?

Tags: power

I asked a question here about using a [waterwheel and an Archemedes screw](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60049/can-an-archemedes-screw-powered-by-a-waterwheel-supply-water-to-a-building) to keep at least the water running in an abandoned facility. The one answer I got so far seemed to imply that wouldn't actually be the most efficient way to accomplish this. This has me wondering now, what could you actually keep running without any external power or maintenance? And yes, I realized waterwheels need maintenance too, so its unlikely they would still be running after a facility was abandoned. Also, from my knowledge when those things are abandoned they normally lock them down so they can't turn anymore. So unless someone could figure out how to unlock it, that's a no-go.

I was thinking of having everything possible being analogue, as demonstrated by my last question. No electricity, just classic mechanics. Obviously this means no lights or other electronics, but that's fine. What else though could you keep running? Could a ram-pump with an on-site well be enough to keep the water on? What about heating? I know about solar heating, but I don't know anything about that.

What all could be kept running? Would you actually require something unusual for everything? I did hear once that the Hoover Dam could keep making power for years without maintenance. In fact, if humans disappeared it may very well be the last power plant to shut down. Of course, it couldn't run forever. Its lubricant would inevitably wear out, and with no one to put more in even it would inevitably shut down. Of course, that may all be moot. Given enough time, everything degrades and collapses, so no matter how something is built even if it doesn't need humans to keep it running it would still collapse one day. I'm more thinking about the short term, such as a few wears or maybe a human lifetime that this place could keep running.

Another problem I'm having is justifying it having all sorts of odd tech in it. Why would they all be in one place? I could see a hobbyist rigging their own home with all sorts of gizmos, but this place was never someone's home. I admit though I haven't decided what its purpose was yet, so that could easily be changed to make this all work.

Comment: This sounds more like it belongs in Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: Worldbuilders often look to the real world for evidence. Its called hard worldbuilding. Which is better to ask this one? A bunch of writers who don't actually know a damned thing they're talking about, or actual engineers that do know what they're doing? They all have to ask people like you to find out this stuff. There's no other way. What, is hard science fiction or realistic stories not allowed now? Must we continue to make stuff that scientists bash as utterly stupid even though we're not allowed to do better? Sorry, bad day.

Comment: A lot of engineers actually visit World Building SE site. The actual problem with this question in particular on Engineering SE is that it asks for extraneous stuff such as odd tech that *might* be in a building and there are no real design constraints or objectives. The building, filled with equipment that serves no apparent purpose, serves no apparent purpose itself and can't really have anything meaningful designed for it.

Comment: Best way to run an abandoned facility is to undo the abandonment, or even better: don't abandon it. As far as power goes, if you think nuclear, the lifespan can be decades instead of years.

Comment: You saying a nuclear reactor can run attended for decades? Then why do they need 24 hour surveillance? I know this because the nuclear plant in town is shut down for half the year, to keep the employees from being exposed to radiation too much.

Comment: I feel like you've decided that having running water means a building is powered.  If you were next to a stream most people would just go get water from the stream.  Water power was used to do things like pump water out (Holland) or grind grains (wheat mills).  Solar power would be the easiest way to keep something going indefinitely.

Comment: "Which is better to ask ... or actual engineers that do know what they're doing?"  The problem is that actual engineers quickly learn that they put a lot of effort into a sensible answer and then the "worldbuilder" says "oh, but that doesn't fit with the plot I'm trying to build, because you see the Princess wears 3" tall heels (or is actually a mollusk with no bones, or whatever) and your idea is totally impractical in that circumstance".  So -- they know what they're doing if they attempt to answer, and they refrain.